# Permutation and characteristic polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, after some manipulations I find:
$$\tilde{A}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & I_n&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&I_n&\cdots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots& \vdots&\ddots &\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&I_n\\ A & 0 &0 &\cdots &0  \end{pmatrix};\;   \mathcal{A}=\begin{pmatrix}  I_n&0&\cdots&0&0\\0&I_n&\cdots&0&0\\ \vdots& \vdots&\ddots &\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&\cdots&I_n&0\\ 0 & 0 &\cdots &0&A  \end{pmatrix} ; \tilde{A},\mathcal{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{kn\times kn}$$
by simple permutation $\tilde{A}$ becomes $\mathcal{A}$.

Q: my objective is to find if there exist, a relation between eigenvalues of $A$ and $\tilde{A}$ (so $\mathcal{A}$) in term of characteristic polynomial?

Is there any relation between $P_\mathcal{A}(\lambda)$ and $P_\tilde{A}(\lambda)$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is a simple rotation of $\tilde{A}$? or just a relation between their eigenvalues?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Should the bottom-right entry of $\mathcal A$ be $A$, or should that entry be a zero instead?

Comment: It's true; just change the place of the first column of $\tilde{A}$ to the last one and you will have $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: aha, I missed the $A$ in the bottom left of $\tilde A$

Comment: It may be convenient to write your matrices in terms of [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).  In particular, we have
$$
\mathcal A = \pmatrix{1\\&\ddots\\&&1\\&&&0} \otimes I_n + \pmatrix{0\\&\ddots\\&&0\\&&&1} \otimes A
$$
and
$$
\tilde A = \left[\pmatrix{0&1\\&0&1\\&&&\ddots\\&&&&1\\1&&&&0} \otimes I_n \right] \mathcal A
$$

Answer (score 1):

I see no easy way to relate the eigenvalues of $\tilde A$ and $\mathcal A$ directly.  However, both of these have eigenvalues that are neatly related to those of $A$.

**Characteristic polynomial of $\mathcal A$**: Note that the vectors of the form
$$
v = \pmatrix{x_1\\\vdots \\ x_{k-1} \\ 0}, \quad v = \pmatrix{0\\ \vdots\\ 0 \\ w}
$$
where $x_i \in \Bbb C^n$ are arbitrary and $w$ is an eigenvector of $A$ can be used to form an eigenbasis of $\mathcal A$.  Conclude that $\mathcal A$ has characteristic polynomial
$$
p_{\mathcal A}(\lambda) = (\lambda - 1)^{n(k-1)}p_{A}(\lambda)
$$
Although we assumed that $A$ is diagonalizable, this carries over to the case where $A$ fails to be diagonalizable by the continuous dependence of the characteristic polynomial on matrix entries.  We could also make an argument appealing to the Jordan form of $A$.

**Characteristic polynomial of $\tilde A$:** a vector $v = (x_1,\dots,x_k)$ will be an eigenvector of $\tilde A$ if and only if we have
$$
\pmatrix{x_2\\ \vdots \\ x_k\\ Ax_1} = \lambda\pmatrix{x_1\\ \vdots \\ x_{k-1} \\ x_k}
$$
That is, the vectors $x_i$ must satisfy
$$
x_i = \lambda x_{i-1} \qquad i=2,\dots,k\\
Ax_1 = \lambda x_k
$$
By substituting, we see that this amounts to 
$$
Ax_1 = \lambda^k x_1
$$
So, $\lambda^k$ will be an eigenvalue of $\tilde A$ whenever $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.  We can use this to conclude that
$$
p_{\tilde A}(\lambda) = p_A(\lambda^k)
$$

Comment: Just about the equation $Ax_1=x_k$ I think you forgot $\lambda$, so $Ax_1=\lambda^{k+1}x_1$. But, the equation $Ax_1=\lambda^k x_1$ remain always valid?

Comment: The missing $\lambda$ was a typo. It’s correct as it currently is, I think.

Comment: If we take $\lambda^k=z$, can we write $arg(\lambda)=\frac{arg(z)}{k}$ ??