# $P_B(x)=P_A(x^k)$, what is the relationship between root of $P_B(x)$ and $P_A(x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $B\in $:
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & I_n&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&I_n&\cdots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots& \vdots&\ddots &\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&I_n\\ A & 0 &0 &\cdots &0  \end{pmatrix}_{(kn)\times(kn)}\ B\in\mathbb{R}^{kn\times kn}$$
So,  $P_B(x)=P_A(x^k)$, $x\in \mathbb{C}$ (see proof here [Permutation and characteristic polynomial of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800736/permutation-and-characteristic-polynomial-of-a-matrix/2801021?noredirect=1#comment5865799_2801021) first answer)

Q: what is the relationship between $P_B(x)$ and $P_A(x)$ if term of their roots (arguments) or in term of eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y$ be a root of $P_A$. Let $x*$ be a $k$th root of $y$. Then

$\begin{align}
0 &= P_A(y) &\mid \text{  $y$ root of $P_A$} \\
  &= P_A((x*)^k) &\mid \text{  $x*$ $k$th root of $y$} \\
  &= P_B(x*)  &\mid \text{  given}
\end{align}$

. Thus, the $k$th roots of an arbitrary root of $P_A$ are roots of $P_B$.

Similarly, let $x*$ be an arbitrary root of $P_B$. Then

$\begin{align}
0 &= P_B(x*) \\
&= P_A((x*)^k)
\end{align}$

. Thus, the $k$th potence of an arbitrary root of $P_B$ is a root of $P_A$.

Comment: It's very helpful, any idea about relationship in term of arguments of roots?

Comment: Hint: If $z \neq 0$ and $n$ is any integer, then $\operatorname{Arg}(z^n) \equiv n\operatorname{Arg}(z) \mod [-\pi, \pi]$  ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Identities))